# PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase not found

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

just made upgrade to 2.3.0 and while compilation get this error:

```
server@server:~/web/server.dev.company.com/public_html$ /usr/bin/php7.1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
    Compilation was started.
    Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 68.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /home/server/web/server.dev.company.com/public_html/app/code/WebShopApps/MatrixRate/test/Unit/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/ImportTest.php on line 36
```

I try to remove this module, but it not solve this trouble.

Comment: PHP version 7.1.26;
composer.json -> "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using PHPUnit version 6, please replace class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' in your test file to 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase'. So it'd look like this:

```
class YourTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
    ...
}
```

Reference : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11114

Comment: some vendor modules (M2.3.1) use the old class `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

Answer (score 2):

For this do some changes into file. Just change this code

```
class MatrixrateTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

to

```
class MatrixrateTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
```

into below files.

```
 Matrixrate/GridTest.php
 Form/Field/ExportTest.php
 Form/Field/ImportTest.php
 Config/Backend/MatrixrateTest.php
 Config/Source/MatrixrateTest.php
```

Than run compilation command your problem is sorted